# Retrieving image from a httpwebrequest on unity using json data

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest

Im building an augmented reality app which involves images retrieved from the internet.

I found a similar basic app that uses pixabay and works great. You type in a search term and it returns all the images from that search, similar to google image search.

The code for that is below.

I dont need the search function, i will just have a button that has a category and when selected, the next scene will show the results of all the images from the website.

An example of the website is https://www.castlefineart.com/artists/robert-oxley#art.

Any help will be much appreciated. As i mentioned, the pixabay code is below.

As i said, i dont need the search function i just need to load all the images from a specific page.

Cheers

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;


/*
 * @author Michael Hässig
 * @email michael.haessig (at) gmail (dot) com
 */
public static class PixabayApi
{
    public static string URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/";

// My API KEY - the api is public but please do not abuse 
public static string KEY = "11701417-557ad1ed3c54b52741fa32e5c";

public static PixabayImageResponse Search(string search)
{
    // create http request
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL + $"? 
 key={KEY}&q={search}");
    // set http method
    request.Method = "GET";
    // send request and auto close stream
    using (HttpWebResponse response =         
(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        // create reader for response stream
        StreamReader reader = new 
StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        // read the full response into a string
        string jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // parse string into response model object
        PixabayImageResponse pixabayImageResponse =         
JsonUtility.FromJson<PixabayImageResponse>(jsonResponse);
        // return result
        return pixabayImageResponse;
       }
   }
```

}

```
[Serializable]
public class PixabayImage
{
public int id;
public string pageURL;
public string type;
public string tags;
public string previewURL;
public int previewWidth;
public int previewHeight;
public string webformatURL;
public int webformatWidth;
public int webformatHeight;
public string largeImageURL;
public string fullHDURL;
public string imageURL;
public int imageWidth;
public int imageHeight;
public int imageSize;
public int views;
public int downloads;
public int favorites;
public int likes;
public int comments;
public int user_id;
public string user;
public string userImageURL;
}

[Serializable]
public class PixabayImageResponse
{
public int total;
public int totalHits;
public List<PixabayImage> hits;
}
```

Comment: Maybe HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL + $"? 
 key={KEY}&q=");

without a {search} tag?

And can't you simply remove the search bar?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.
As i said i dont actually need a search function, i literally need it to go, for example here:

https://www.castlefineart.com/art?artists[]=1

which is the format for all of the pages and retrieve all images.

Also, im a beginner at this, so apologies if i need it dumbing down a bit.

Comment: I understand that it needs to go away, but isn't that simply removing the html tag?.

And you can also remove the method 

static PixabayImageResponse Search(string search)

You need to clarify what you want. It's a bit vague.

Comment: The app will have a list of different artists. When you select one, the next page will be a page of images showing their work.

These will be images pulled from a particular website corresponding to the artist

Comment: Fair, if I was you, I would make a dropdown box. Clicking on the dropdown box will call the API search function: http://jsfiddle.net/sfGug/2/

The only way to make this possible is to change the front-end